# FullCallendar eventContent hook - how to tell if the event is single day or multi day?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using the eventContent hook in FullCalendar to send back JSX so that my events are customized in the calendar.  Works great.  However, I'd like to format them differently based on if the events are single day or multi day.  In the default view, single day events have a colored dot and multi day events have a colored bar.

The arg that gets passed into the eventContent hook has things like isStart, isEnd, etc., but nothing about isSingleDay or whatever.

Is there an attribute in the arg somewhere that has this info and I'm just not seeing it, or do I simply need to just check start and end and calculate myself if the event is single day or multi day?

Answer (score 1):

For now, I ended up just using moment.js, since I was already using the moment plugin for FullCallendar.  So, I'm just taking the start and end date values returned in the eventContent hook and using moment:

```
...
<FullCalendar
    plugins={[
        momentPlugin,
        ...
    ]}
    eventContent={getEventDisplay}
    ...
/>
...
const getEventDisplay = (arg: EventContentArg) => {
    const isSingleDay = isEventSingleDay(arg.event.start?.getTime() || 0, arg.event.end?.getTime() || 0);
    ...
}
...
const isEventSingleDay = (start: number, end: number): boolean => {
    const startDate = moment(start);
    const endDate = moment(end);

    if (endDate.isSame(startDate, 'date')) return true;
    return false;
}
```